# Remove javascript comment from asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, regex

suppose i wrote my javascript in my aspx page like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop() {
    // test 1

    /*  test1
        test2
        test3
    */
     myfunc1();
     myfunc1();
     myfunc1();
}
```

now at runtime i want to remove all javascript comment from the page using regex from render method of the page. so just tell me what regex i need to use.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
        {
            base.Render(htmlwriter);
            string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();

            if ((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RemoveWhitespace") + string.Empty).Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {

                // regex for removing html comment
                html = Regex.Replace(html, @"((<!-- )((?!<!-- ).)*( -->))(\r\n)*", String.Empty);
                // regex for removing line break & carriage return
                html = html.Replace(";\r\n", ";");
            }
            writer.Write(html.Trim());
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats is working till now and what is not ?

Comment: everything is working still now but getting error if i have the javascript single line or multiline comment in the aspx page. i need to also remove javascript single line and multiline comment from the page if exist. so plzz tell me what i need to add in my code to remove javascript single line and multiline comment from the page if exist. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
((\/\*[\s\S]+?\*\/)|(\/\/.+))
```

http://regexr.com?2v8t8

Comment: it tips work but few line of code has been distorted. this code given below.  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.jQuery ||
        document.write("<script type='text\/javascript' src=<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>><\/script>");
    </script> what will be the fixed if i use ur reg expression. thanks